# glassfish authenticating @Webservice calls

Tags: java, web-services, security, glassfish-3

We have a java ee 6 application deployed in glassfish v3.01, we would like to expose some of our EJB's as webservices but we are having trouble securing and authenticating the webservice endpoints. We are using a custom login module and realm. How do we go about authenticating the webservice calls?

Thanks
Gideon

```
@WebService
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({Role.WEBMASTER, Role.ACCOUNTADMIN, Role.ACCOUNTUSER})
@RolesAllowed({Role.WEBMASTER,Role.ACCOUNTADMIN,Role.ACCOUNTUSER})
public class SmppService
{
    @EJB
    private SmppEjb ejbRef;// Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose

    @WebMethod(operationName = "sendMessage")
    @Oneway
    public void sendMessage(@WebParam(name = "cellNumber")
    String cellNumber, @WebParam(name = "message")
    String message) {
        ejbRef.sendMessage(cellNumber, message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The username and password go in the http header.  All soap clients should have a way to specify this.  For instance, in our ruby code that uses soap4r it looks like this

```
instance = eval(@gateways[gateway]).new(url)
instance.options["protocol.http.auth"] << [url, @auth_data[user][0], @auth_data[user][1]]
instance.options['protocol.http.ssl_config.verify_mode'] = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

@auth_data[user][0] is the username and @auth_data[user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) is the password.

If you are creating the header by hand, you have to use [Digest Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)